# Sending Tableau worksheet to customers automatically via email

Tags: tableau-desktop

We just started using Tableau Desktop.  We have a Tableau worksheet with a list report we would like to send to our customer automatically via email every month.  Is that possible?  We have the customer's email address available in the database and would like to send reports to customers with their data only.  In Cognos I used a burst function to do this.  Is something similar available in Tableau?

Comment: Tableau Desktop in not meant to do this kind of tasks.
Sharing contets with other users is something you should do with Tableau Server/Online

Comment: Thanks @FabioFantoni.  Do you know if Tableau server allows sending reports and dashboards in PDF format to email addresses for people who are not necessarily Tableau users?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, Desktop is not meant for these tasks.

Anyway using Tableau Server/Online, the closest thing to what you want to accomplish could be subscription:

https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/subscribe.htm

By the way, this feature involves registered Tableau users.